# How to Recover GAC Assembly files which deleted by mistakenly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, ssms, visual-studio-2019, gac

Visual studio and SSMS application are not opening. Only Splash screen visible for 2 3 seconds then  it exit and nothing happen because I have deleted the files under GAC assembly folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly folder from the another system and paste it in the system in which I was getting issue.

Resolved the Visual studio and SSMS problem.